# Python asyncio: stop the loop when one coroutine is done

Tags: python, coroutine, python-asyncio

I'm quite new in this python asyncio topic. I have a simple question:
I have a task containing two coroutines to be run concurrently. First coroutine(my_coroutine) would just print something continuously until second_to_sleep is reached. The second coroutine(seq_coroutine) would call 4 other coroutines sequentially one after the other. My goal is to stop the loop at the end of seq_coroutine whenever it is completely finished. To be exact, I want my_coroutine be alive until seq_coroutine is finished. Can someone help me with that?

My code is like this:

```
import asyncio

async def my_coroutine(task,  seconds_to_sleep = 3):
    print("{task_name} started\n".format(task_name=task))
    for i in range(1, seconds_to_sleep):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("\n{task_name}: second {seconds}\n".format(task_name=task, seconds=i))

async def coroutine1():
    print("coroutine 1 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 1 finished\n")


async def coroutine2():
    print("coroutine 2 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 2 finished\n")


async def coroutine3():
    print("coroutine 3 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 3 finished\n")


async def coroutine4():
    print("coroutine 4 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 4 finished\n")


async def seq_coroutine():
    await coroutine1()
    await coroutine2()
    await coroutine3()
    await coroutine4()

def main():
    main_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = [asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine("task1", 11)),
            asyncio.ensure_future(seq_coroutine())]
    try:
        print('loop is started\n')
        main_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*task))
    finally:
        print('loop is closed')
        main_loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the output of this program:

```
loop is started

task1 started

coroutine 1 started

task1: second 1

coroutine 1 finished
coroutine 2 started

task1: second 2

coroutine 2 finished
coroutine 3 started

task1: second 3

coroutine 3 finished
coroutine 4 started

task1: second 4

coroutine 4 finished

task1: second 5
task1: second 6
task1: second 7
task1: second 8
task1: second 9
task1: second 10

loop is closed
```

I only want to have something like this:

```
loop is started

task1 started

coroutine 1 started

task1: second 1

coroutine 1 finished
coroutine 2 started

task1: second 2

coroutine 2 finished
coroutine 3 started

task1: second 3

coroutine 3 finished
coroutine 4 started

task1: second 4

coroutine 4 finished

loop is closed
```

Comment: Why not just `run_until_complete(seq_coroutine)`?

Comment: The idea of doing this concurrently is more than just sleeping and printing. "my_coroutine" is a process of listening to something else and should run in parallel with seq_coroutine, but to make it simpler to ask, i just make it shorter.

Answer (score 10):

I just found a suitable solution for my problem.
I won't remove my post and I'll post my solution so that it may help others who face the same question.
I used `asyncio.wait(task, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)` and it will return the result whenever the first task is finished.
This is the solution:

```
import asyncio
from asyncio.tasks import FIRST_COMPLETED
from concurrent.futures import CancelledError

async def my_coroutine(task,  seconds_to_sleep = 3):
    print("{task_name} started\n".format(task_name=task))
    for i in range(1, seconds_to_sleep):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("\n{task_name}: second {seconds}\n".format(task_name=task, seconds=i))

async def coroutine1():
    print("coroutine 1 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 1 finished\n")


async def coroutine2():
    print("coroutine 2 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 2 finished\n")


async def coroutine3():
    print("coroutine 3 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 3 finished\n")


async def coroutine4():
    print("coroutine 4 started")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("coroutine 4 finished\n")


async def seq_coroutine(loop):
    await coroutine1()
    await coroutine2()
    await coroutine3()
    await coroutine4()

def main():
    main_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    task = [asyncio.ensure_future(my_coroutine("task1", 11)),
            asyncio.ensure_future(seq_coroutine(main_loop))]
    try:
        print('loop is started\n')
        done, pending = main_loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(task, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED))
        print("Completed tasks: {completed}\nPending tasks: {pending}".format(completed = done, pending = pending))

        #canceling the tasks
        for task in pending:
            print("Cancelling {task}: {task_cancel}".format(task=task, task_cancel=task.cancel()))

    except CancelledError as e:
        print("Error happened while canceling the task: {e}".format(e=e))
    finally:
        print('loop is closed')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable to signal to another coroutine.  `asyncio.Event` is usually used:

```
import asyncio

import random


async def clock(name, event):
    print("* {} started".format(name))
    i = 0
    while not event.is_set():
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        i += 1
        print("* {}: {}".format(name, i))
    print("* {} done".format(name))
    return i


async def coro(x):
    print("coro() started", x)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.5))
    print("coro() finished", x)


async def seq_coroutine(name):
    event = asyncio.Event()
    clock_task = asyncio.ensure_future(clock(name, event))
    # await asyncio.sleep(0) # if you want to give a chance to clock() to start
    await coro(1)
    await coro(2)
    await coro(3)
    await coro(4)
    event.set()
    i = await clock_task
    print("Got:", i)


def main():
    main_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    main_loop.run_until_complete(seq_coroutine("foo"))
    main_loop.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

You can also use `await event.wait()` to block a piece of code until the event is set:

```
async def xxx(event):
    print("xxx started")
    await event.wait()
    print("xxx ended")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to do the same thing, which I think is cleaner in representing the dependence between jobs:

```py
import asyncio

async def poll():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print("First", i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        print("Second", i)
        i += 1
        await asyncio.sleep(20)
        
async def stop():
    poller = asyncio.ensure_future(poll())
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    poller.cancel()

main_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
main_loop.run_until_complete(stop())
main_loop.close()
```

Basically, instead of breaking the entire event loop on a single job ending and then cancelling the job there, we just cancel the dependent job directly when the parent job finishes.